# Finding unique values in dataframe and multipling from another unique dataframe- Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a master list of data and I wish to multiply particular values by a factor which is located in a separate dataframe. Both data frames have two unique identifiers to assist with the multiplication.

So in the example below, I wish to identify the row with iden1 and iden2 from the lookup dataframe, grab the factor, then multiply the corresponding row in the master data sheet.

```
import pandas as pd

a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4

x=100
y=200

data = [[a, x, 1],
          [a, y, 1],
          [b, x, 1],
          [b, y, 1],
          [c, x, 1],
          [c, y, 1],
          [d, x, 1],
          [d, y, 1]]

master_datasheet = pd.DataFrame(data,columns =["iden1", "iden2", "value"])
         

lookup =  [[a, x, 2],

          [b, x, 1.5],

          [c, x, 3],

          [d, x, 4]]

lookup_datasheet = pd.DataFrame(lookup, columns = ['iden1', 'iden2', 'factor'])

print(variables)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first left merge `master_daasheet` and `lookup_datasheet` then take only the `factor` column and `fillna` with 1 so the record for which factor doesn't exist remain intact, then finally multiply using `mul` with the `value` column of the `master_datasheet`

```py
master_datasheet['value']=(master_datasheet['value']
                            .mul(master_datasheet.merge(lookup_datasheet, 
                                how='left')['factor'].fillna(1))
                           )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
   iden1  iden2  value
0      1    100    2.0
1      1    200    1.0
2      2    100    1.5
3      2    200    1.0
4      3    100    3.0
5      3    200    1.0
6      4    100    4.0
7      4    200    1.0
```

Comment: that does work but what happens if the original datasheet were not 1 and varied?

Comment: @mhooper, It works in any cases as long as the data has the same structure to the sample data you have in the question.